# Android Java.io.FileNotFoundException when trying to download and save a video

Tags: android, exception, download, movies

I'm trying to develop an app which provides many movies and you can play it or download the movie.

That app works fine in my **rooted** Galaxy S4 (Kitkat API:19),
but when I install it on another device and try to download the movie it gives my the exception `Java.io.FileNotFoundException`, I don't know what's the problem

That's my code

```
package nmc.net.blue.bluenet_nmc;

import android.content.Context;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLConnection;

/**
 * Created by ElHoni on 5/3/2016.
 */
public class DownloadFileAsync extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {



    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... aurl) {
        int count;

        try {
            URL url = new URL(aurl[0]);
            URLConnection conexion = url.openConnection();
            conexion.connect();

            File folder = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() +
                    File.separator + "BlueNet");

            if (!folder.exists()) {
                folder.mkdirs();
            }


            String outputPath=folder.getPath()+"/"+aurl[1];

            BufferedInputStream input = new BufferedInputStream(url.openStream());
            FileOutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(outputPath);

            byte data[] = new byte[1024];

            long total = 0;

            while ((count = input.read(data, 0, 1024)) != -1) {
                output.write(data, 0, count);

            }

            output.flush();
            output.close();
            input.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            String err = e.toString();

        }
        return null;

    }
    protected void onProgressUpdate(String... progress) {
        Log.d("ANDRO_ASYNC",progress[0]);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String unused) {

        //Toast.makeText(full_screen_video.this, "", 5);

    }

}
```

and by the way
i put this permissions in manufests

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

any help please

Comment: You should use `DownloadManager` instead of your approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I said, you should use `DownloadManager` for what you want.

Here is a method which downloads a file from a given URL.

```
public static void downloadFileFromUrl(String url, String dir, String fileName, DownloadManager downloadManager) {
    Uri downloadUri = Uri.parse(url);
    DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(downloadUri);

    request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(dir, fileName);
    request.setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED);
    request.setVisibleInDownloadsUi(true);
    downloadManager.enqueue(request);
}
```

Instantiate `DownloadManager` like this:

```
DownloadManager downloadManager = (DownloadManager) getSystemService(DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
```

Remember to add `WRITE_PERMISSION` and `INTERNET_PERMISSION` and don't forget that in Android M or newer you should check the permissions in a different way.

Comment: unfortunately it still didnt work
i create the method and i call it from the button Listener

Comment: Can you post your full logcat log?

Comment: please describe the argument
uri=uri of what?
path=path of what?
filename: is the file i want to download or where i want to download on my device??

Comment: The URL of the file you want to download, the path (folder under the SD card, ex: Pictures, Downloads... ) and the name of the file you want to store.

Comment: the code doesn't work, it doesn't give any error but it don't download the file too

Comment: It does work, I have tested it in my app. Can you post how are u calling it?

Comment: or see it here 

that's how i call it

 DownloadManager downloadManager = (DownloadManager) getSystemService(DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);

                    downloadFileFromUrl(path, fileName, downloadManager);

Comment: i said that your answer is ok because it near from true, but still not work :)

Comment: I want to see the content of your `url, path and fileName` variables.

Comment: url="192.168.1.5:8080/BlueNet_NMCvideoShare/blue_elephant.mp4";

path=Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + File.separator + "BlueNet";


fileName=blue_elephant.mp4

Comment: @M.Honi `path` must be only "/BlueNet" as `request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(path, fileName);` already sets the destination to the external SD card plus the dir you pass. (Maybe I've should called the variable `dir` instead of `path`, I'm gonna edit it.

Comment: ok, i wanna try this solution and if it doesn't work I'll wait you while you edit your answer

Comment: still not working, it doesn't give any error but not download any thing :(

i put break point to see what happened exactly but I found nothing

Comment: I can't help you more without knowing more about your app's code, the problem is not in the download method.

Comment: so, what do you suggest?
do you want me to send you the the whole main activity?
if you so, give me your email cause i can't send it here

Comment: You can upload the important files to some website and post the link here, so I can check it out more effusively.

Comment: what file do you need?

Comment: Activities and/or fragments where you call the download method, manifest, the app gradle file and helper classes (if you are using them)

Comment: it's only main activity
i'll post it here as an answer ok?

Comment: i can't edit my question because now i'm using donload manager

Comment: So, have you posted it anywhere?

Comment: i post it in new question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37082354/android-download-manager-not-working