# Download Manager not working

Tags: android, video, android-download-manager

I'm trying to develop app that show videos and you can Download it
i'm using Download Manager class but it didn't work, also it didn't give me any error :(

**this is my download manager code:**

```
    public void downloadFileFromUrl(String url, String fileName) {

        String filePath=Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + File.separator + "BlueNet";

        File folder = new File(filePath);

        if (!folder.exists()) {
            folder.mkdirs();
        }

        try {

        Uri downloadUri = Uri.parse(url);
        DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(downloadUri);

        request.setAllowedNetworkTypes(DownloadManager.Request.NETWORK_WIFI);
        request.allowScanningByMediaScanner();

        request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir("/BlueNet/",fileName);
        request.setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED);
        request.setVisibleInDownloadsUi(true);
        DownloadManager downloadManager = (DownloadManager)getApplicationContext().getSystemService(DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
        long id= downloadManager.enqueue(request);
            Toast.makeText(this, fileName, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            Toast.makeText(this, filePath, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }

        catch (Exception ex){
            Toast.makeText(this, ex.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
```

and this is how I'm calling it

```
downloadFileFromUrl(path, fileName);
```

where:

**path**: "192.168.1.5:8080/BlueNet_NMC/blue_elephant.mp4"

**filename**: "blue_elephant.mp4"

and i already give this permissions to manifests

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

so please any help

Comment: Have you tried "/BlueNet" instead of "/BlueNet/"? Also, AFAIK there's no need to check if that folder exists, `DownloadManager` does it for you.

Comment: ok i delete check steep

Comment: Have you tried to download an image or something from the Internet instead of a file from your local network?

Comment: no, but when i put my link in browser i can download it

Comment: Just try it and tell me if it works.

Comment: OMG, it's working with link from internet, so what's the problem

and the other issue that the download arrow doesn't appear

Comment: `DownloadManager` only handles http/https requests. It's weird the download arrow should be appearing, try not to allow the check by media scanner or try a different `Visibility`.

Comment: but my link also http "http:// 192.168.1.5:8080/BlueNet_NMC/video_share/blue_elephant.mp4"

Comment: i made space between http and 192 to you can see it

Comment: Maybe it's not using HTTP protocol to transfer the file in your local network. Which server are u using?

Comment: i'm using wamp server on my laptop

Comment: So I don't know exactly why it's not working with your local network url, I should check more thigns but I think it's a common issue.

Comment: ok, please put your answer to mark it as true answer
thank you :)

Comment: @M.Honi I think that Download Manager *does* support HTTPS, take a look at [this](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DownloadManager.Request?hl=en#public-constructors_2) (I'm still trying to successfully download an image that way though, but I've been at it only for some hours as of now)

Comment: it's downloading, but finally it's getting failed to download. file doesn't exist at specified directory.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As I said in the comments, `DownloadManager` only handles requests starting with `http://` or `https://` as you can see [in the docs](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/android/app/DownloadManager.html).

I don't know exactly what's the problem because I lack information about your server, but I think it's a common issue, so you should avoid using an IP address without providing that scheme.

Comment: Sorry to contradict, but it seems that HTTPS is indeed supported. Take a look at [this link](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DownloadManager.Request?hl=en#public-constructors_2), where they indicate: `Uri: the HTTP or HTTPS URI to download. `

Comment: I didn't mean to say that, I have updated my answer to reflect what I wanted to say. Thanks for pointing that out, @DarkCygnus!

Answer (score 1):

I had a problem when downloading files with an HTTP URL using the `DownloadManger` class; but then I did the following and the problem was fixed.

**Instead of this code:**

```
String url = "http://masteranime.ir/music/best/Dragon Ball GT Dan Dan Kokoro Hikareteku.mp3";
DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(Uri.parse(url));
```

**use this code:**

```
String url = "http://masteranime.ir/music/best/Dragon Ball GT Dan Dan Kokoro Hikareteku.mp3";
DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(Uri.parse(url).replaceAll(" ","%20"));
```

Answer (score 0):

### You have problem in this line - `request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir("/BlueNet/",fileName);`

Just remove this line or make directory in another way.

Answer (score 0):

```
request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir("/BlueNet/", fileName);
```

You have to mention directory as first argument here. `/BlueNet/` is not a directory.